# Using Ramda with Typescript, passing down the types

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I have this small function, ***firstOrNull***:

```
import { propOr } from 'ramda'

export const firstOrNull = propOr(null, '0')
```

And I want to use with a property that returns `QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>[]`

```
const organization = firstOrNull(snapshot.docs)?.data() as Organization
```

Because the lack of typing on `firstOrNull`, I got the error:

> Object is of type 'unknown'

What I need to do to use the correct typing on firstOrNull?

[image]

May be change to something like that:

```
export const firstOrNull:<T[]> = propOr<null, T, number>(null, 0)
```

Comment: `npm install @types/ramda`, see link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ramda

Comment: I already have `@types/ramda` installed

Comment: Is `snapshot.docs` properly typed?

Comment: Yes. It properly typed with `QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>[]`

Comment: May be I need something like this: export const firstOrNull:<T[]> = propOr<null, T, number>(null, 0) (I updated my question with this)

Comment: pls share `minimum` reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add explicit type to `firstOrNull` that depends on the array it receives, so it can infer the correct type:

```
export const firstOrNull: <T>(arr: T[]) => T | null = propOr(null, '0')
```

Comment: Whenever the `@types/ramda` stops inferring the correct types, just add explicit typing to solve it. I hope they'll improve the `@types/ramda` soon.

Comment: Most of us on the Ramda team, know little about TS, and we depend on the people who maintain those typing files.  I believe recent changes have meant that TS is at least close to being able to support Ramda's more complex signatures, but I don't know if it's complete or what gaps there are.  I'm guessing that those who do maintain these types would appreciate help from those who know both Ramda and TS.